# Android studio : No variants found

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOKyW.jpg)
Hi I'm learning  Android studio new and I bought the source from CodeCanyon and solved some errors, but I got stuck in this error:
No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.
I checked cdk tools and everything seems fine and I also searched for answers and tried them but I couldn't solve this error.

here is my code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.quraan.farroukh'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }


    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    productFlavors {


    }
}


dependencies{
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
        gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:Grav:1.1'
    implementation 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'io.saeid:fab-loading:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

}
```

Comment: could you screenshot your android studio screen, especially the left bottom screen with built variants tab

Comment: i have edit my post and add an screenshot

Comment: Not sure though, try Build >Rebuild project option

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you probably didn't install SDK 29.
Go to File->Settings->Appearance and Behaviour->System Settings->Android SDK
Check the specific version of API Level and install it if it's missing